# HP MicroServer Gen 8 RAM

Tags: memory, hp, hp-proliant

So my MicroServer currently have 1x4gb RAM installed in it.
I would like to get this upgraded to the maximum supported, 16GB.

DDR3 ECC 2x8gb is rather expensive. Would the server be happy with non ecc memory so I can get cheaper off-brand RAM?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know the G8 will work just fine with some of non-ECC [Home Server Show thread about it](https://homeservershow.com/forums/topic/5899-gen8-memory-non-ecc/) I got an N36L (ye older gen) with 1x8GB and 1x4GB generic RAM and it works for like 6 months now without any hiccups.